# How to create check box automatically depends on folder selected using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, checkbox

I need to create a checkbox automatically depends on folder I selected. I create ComboBox, then in the ComboBox, I can select which folder that I want to select. Inside of my folder, I have some file. The file consist of some extension file. I just need to pick 2 extension file from the folder, example(*.txt and *.csv).

After I select the folder, the checkBox will create automatically, the total of the checkBox depends on how many file exist in that folder with specific extension(*.txt and *.csv).

In my code, I already do some stuff, which is select the folder that I need to select, but still struggle with the checkBox. Anyone can help me please. Thank you so much. I really appreciate for the help.

I put my script in the ##2nd Updated.

#### Updated

Consider to @f6a4 answer, this is the result
The first picture is I just use this path to get the folder

```
'D:\Data\'
```

[image]

In the first picture, I already double click the folder1 and folder2, but the file do not appear.

The second picture, I specify the folder path

```
'D:\Data\folder1'
```

[image]

The second picture, the file appear because I specify the folder in the path, so the folder name do not appear in the `please select folder box` and return this error `$CTRL_ListFolder.Items.AddRange( (Get-ChildItem -Path $GH.CurrentFold ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException`

### 2n Updated

I updated my script. But the file only appear 1, once I click the folder. And when I change to click other folder, It does not appear the file.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Global:status = "inactive" 
$Global:array = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.text                       = "BPS Image Automation Utility"
$Form.BackColor                  = "#f6f6f6"
$Form.AutoSize                   = $true
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"
$Form.MaximizeBox                = $false
$Form.startposition              = "centerscreen"
$Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Please select the image"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,50)
$Label1.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Label1.ForeColor                = "#000000"
$label1.AutoSize                 = $true

$Button3                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button3.BackColor               = "#136aa4"
$Button3.ForeColor               = "#ffffff"
$Button3.text                    = "Done"
$Button3.width                   = 90
$Button3.height                  = 32
$Button3.AutoSize = $true
$Button3.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$Button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $False
# $Button3.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1700,920)
$Button3.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
# $Button3.Visible                 = $false

$Button2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.BackColor               = "#136aa4"
$Button2.ForeColor               = "#ffffff"
$Button2.text                    = "Delete"
$Button2.width                   = 90
$Button2.height                  = 32
$Button2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $False
$Button2.AutoSize = $true
# $Button2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1600,920)
$Button2.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
# $Button2.Visible                 = $false

$Panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$panel.Dock = "Fill"
$panel.ColumnCount = 1
$panel.RowCount = 1
$panel.CellBorderStyle = "single"
$panel.ColumnStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 100)))
$panel.RowStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 100)))


$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.text                  = "Job Handling"
$Groupbox1.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,9'
$Groupbox1.AutoSize              = $true
$Groupbox1.ForeColor             = "#032d5d"
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,13)
$Groupbox1.Padding               = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Padding -ArgumentList (0,5,5,0)
$Groupbox1.Dock                  = "fill"
$Groupbox1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True

$Groupbox2                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox2.text                  = "Job Information"
$Groupbox2.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,9'
$Groupbox2.AutoSize              = $true
$Groupbox2.ForeColor             = "#032d5d"
$Groupbox2.Dock                  = "None"
$Groupbox2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True

$ComboBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox1.BackColor              = "#e8f3ff"
$ComboBox1.width                  = 190
$ComboBox1.height                 = 20
$ComboBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(35,80)
$ComboBox1.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,12'
$ComboBox1.AutoSize               = $true
$ImageList = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory "D:\Process")
foreach ($img in $ImageList) {
    $ComboBox1.Items.Add($img)
}
$ComboBox1.Add_Click({
    if($ComboBox1.SelectedItem){
        $Checkbox.Visible = $true
    }
})

$Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Checkboxes = @()
$y = 20
$files = Get-ChildItem "D:\Process\$img" -Filter *.txt, *.csv
$files
foreach ($file in $files)
{    

    $Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $Checkbox.Text = $file
    $Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,$y) 
    $Checkbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(330,20) 
    $y += 30
    $Groupbox2.Controls.Add($Checkbox) 
    $Checkboxes += $Checkbox
    $Checkbox.Visible = $false
}

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Panel))
$Panel.controls.AddRange(@($Groupbox1))
$Groupbox1.Controls.AddRange(@($Groupbox2, $ComboBox1, $Label1, $Button3, $Button2))

[void]$Form.Show()

$g2w = $Form.Width - 90
$g2h = $Form.Height - 270
$g2h

$Groupbox2.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(35,110)
$Groupbox2.size                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($g2w,$g2h)
$Groupbox2.AutoSize              = $true

$bt2_w = $g2w - 55
$bt2_h = $g2h + 130
$Button2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($bt2_w,$bt2_h)


$bt3_w = $g2w - 160
$Button3.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($bt3_w,$bt2_h)

$Form.Visible = $false
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I am not sure i understand entirely. But if ur intention is to display a checkbox when some criteria is satisfied, why dont u just create the checkbox but keep the `display` property to `false`. You can toggle it to `true` when the criteria is satisfied. It is much easier approach than to spin up a checkbox during runtime.

Comment: But the problem is, I don't know how many checkbox that I should create, because the total of the files is change sometime.

Comment: You want a checkbox for every csv/txt file found?

Comment: Yes, I do @f6a4

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you want. By double click on a Directory you can browse through subdirectories as well.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# Global variables

$GH = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

$GH.FolderPath        = 'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\csvfiles'
$GH.CurrentFolderPath = $GH.FolderPath
$GH.FileMask          = @('*.txt','*.csv')

# windows form

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Visible = $false
[void]$form.SuspendLayout()
$form.Text = "File Selection"
$form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,430) 
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle

# tab control

$CTRL_TabCtrl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$CTRL_TabCtrl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5,5)
$CTRL_TabCtrl.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(310,420)
[void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_TabCtrl)

$CTRL_Tab1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$CTRL_Tab1.AutoSize = $true
$CTRL_Tab1.Text = 'Main'
$CTRL_Tab1.TabIndex = 1
[void]$CTRL_TabCtrl.Controls.Add($CTRL_Tab1)

# list folder

$CTRL_label10 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$CTRL_label10.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10) 
$CTRL_label10.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$CTRL_label10.Name = 'Label10'
$CTRL_label10.Text = 'Please select a folder:'
[void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_label10) 

$CTRL_ListFolder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$CTRL_ListFolder.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
$CTRL_ListFolder.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,60) 
$CTRL_ListFolder.SelectionMode = [System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode]::One
$CTRL_ListFolder.Items.AddRange( (Get-ChildItem -Path $GH.CurrentFolderPath -Directory).Name  )
$CTRL_ListFolder.Enabled = $true
$CTRL_ListFolder.Add_MouseDoubleClick( { 
    $listFolder_innerevent = $true
    if( $CTRL_ListFolder.SelectedItem -eq '..' ) {
        $GH.CurrentFolderPath = $GH.CurrentFolderPath.Substring( 0, $GH.CurrentFolderPath.LastIndexOf( '\' ) )
        [void]$CTRL_ListFolder.Items.Clear()
        if( $GH.CurrentFolderPath.Length -gt $GH.FolderPath.Length ) {
            [void]$CTRL_ListFolder.Items.Add( '..' )
        }
        $CTRL_ListFolder.Items.AddRange( (Get-ChildItem -Path $GH.CurrentFolderPath -Directory).Name  )

        [void]$CTRL_CheckListBox.Items.Clear()
        $files = (Get-ChildItem -Path ($GH.CurrentFolderPath + '\*') -Include $GH.FileMask -File ).Name
        if( $files ) {
            [void]$CTRL_CheckListBox.Items.AddRange( $files )
        }
     }
     else {
         if( (Get-ChildItem -Path ($GH.CurrentFolderPath + '\' + $CTRL_ListFolder.SelectedItem) -Directory).Name ) {
            $GH.CurrentFolderPath += '\' + $CTRL_ListFolder.SelectedItem
            [void]$CTRL_ListFolder.Items.Clear()
            [void]$CTRL_ListFolder.Items.Add( '..' )
            [void]$CTRL_ListFolder.Items.AddRange( (Get-ChildItem -Path $GH.CurrentFolderPath -Directory).Name )

            [void]$CTRL_CheckListBox.Items.Clear()
            $files = (Get-ChildItem -Path ($GH.CurrentFolderPath + '\*') -Include $GH.FileMask -File ).Name
            if( $files ) {
                [void]$CTRL_CheckListBox.Items.AddRange( $files )
            }
         }
     }
 } )
[void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_ListFolder) 

# list folder with check boxes for files

$CTRL_label12 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$CTRL_label12.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100) 
$CTRL_label12.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$CTRL_label12.Name = 'Label12'
$CTRL_label12.Text = 'Files found:'
[void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_label12) 


$CTRL_CheckListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListbox
$CTRL_CheckListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$CTRL_CheckListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,230) 
$CTRL_CheckListBox.CheckOnClick = $true
$CTRL_CheckListBox.Enabled = $true
$files = (Get-ChildItem -Path ($GH.CurrentFolderPath + '\*') -Include $GH.FileMask -File ).Name
if( $files ) {
    [void]$CTRL_CheckListBox.Items.AddRange( $files )
}
[void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_CheckListBox) 

$CTRL_OKButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CTRL_OKButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(70,365)
$CTRL_OKButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CTRL_OKButton1.Text = 'OK'
$CTRL_OKButton1.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $CTRL_OKButton1
[void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_OKButton1)

$CTRL_CancelButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CTRL_CancelButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,365)
$CTRL_CancelButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CTRL_CancelButton1.Text = 'Cancel'
$CTRL_CancelButton1.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CTRL_CancelButton1
[void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_CancelButton1)

[void]$form.ResumeLayout()

$userInput = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($userInput -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    # User clicked OK Button
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @f6a4, Thank you for your answer. I tried it, this is not what I need, the folder that I need to select should be in the comboBox. I also try to double click the folder, the checkBox is not appear.

Comment: hi @f6a4 I upload the picture of result with your script in the updated part.

Comment: I've checked this here and all is working very well. You are able to browse subdirectories starting from the main folder up and down and the found files will be listed in the second listbox. For folder navigation a listbox is more comfortable than a drop down control. I've added a screenshot as well.

Comment: Hi @f6a4 but it still not working for me :( may I know which PS version do you use?